# How to parse contents of PHP file_get_contents as HTML in jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a client-side Javascript script calling a PHP function, which then calls file_get_contents on a URL.  This is then sent back to the Javascript script, which is supposed to parse the HTML that was returned.

I have currently implemented the script as follows:

PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
  $myURL=$_GET['url'];
  $homepage = file_get_contents($myURL);
  echo $homepage;
}
?>
```

Javascript:

```
 $.ajax({
  url: 'wp-content/plugins/InContext/php/get_url.php',
  async: false,
  data: { url: buildUrl(dataType,ticker,source) },
  success: function(output) {
      pageHtml = output; 
      alert(pageHtml);
   }
 });

var divWrapper = $('<div></div>');
divWrapper.html(pageHtml);
```

However, this gives me an error that says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Event' of undefined.
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Do I need to convert the pageHtml into a string or something to parse it using jQuery?

Comment: `file_get_contents` function in jquery???? Can you give a link that describes that function..??

Comment: you can try with  `.load(),` or `.get()` like Akhilraj says

Comment: are you including `php.js` file in your page. if you are using so. then `file_get_contents` function will work.

Comment: may be this link will help you http://phpjs.org/functions/file_get_contents/

Comment: @PhilemonphilipKunjumon I just added how the JS calls the PHP function

Comment: Are you sure the HTML is correct? Sometimes jQuery hicks up on things like `id="foo-bar"`, i.e. hyphens in an identifier attribute.

Comment: @Jack Okay, it looks like that might be it.  However, I'm scraping from other pages so I can't change the HTML that the PHP function returns.  How would you suggest getting rid of the dashes?

Comment: You'd have to use `DOMDocument` on the PHP side to address that particular issue or don't use jQuery ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try `.load()`, or `.get()` functions in jquery

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem, as Jack mentioned, was the fact that the HTML I was returning was malformed.  I ended up using a PHP HTML parser in order to find the element I was specifically looking for.

You can find what I used here: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/